# Record a playing song

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm totally new with audio framework. I would like to have a feature in my app. 
When playing a clip/song, I want to record that song at the same time. I think there are two cases here. It's the best if I can record what is playing (the identical version). 
Otherwise, if it's impossible, can I record everything (including noise from outside world) at the same time?

Comment: This technically would violate Apple's app sandbox policy. There probably is a way to do this, but apple probably won't let you do it in an official app.

Comment: Can you explain how it violates Apple's policy?

Comment: The audio stream belongs to the app playing it, and iOS.

The Sandbox paradigm means that a resource owned by your App can't be used by another App. Resource here means Audio/Video stream or file.  Recording the real output from the speakers MIGHT be a grey area, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I come up with the second approach which records everything including noise from the outside world. It works but I'm not sure it'll be approved by Apple.